# PHP How to replace ForEach loops in 2D arrays matching values problem with helper function

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently in the proccess of improving my code to be more readable, faster and safer to become a mid-senior developer and I often stumble across code parts that I cant figure how to simplify.
So I develop a crud operation in laravel and I have a form where a user can add, edit or delete an image from a property. We are interested in the delete operation for this particular problem. The way the form submits the images is shown below in the code:

```
@foreach ($property_images as $key => $image)
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('Link', 'Image Link:*') !!}
        {!! Form::text("images[$key][link]", $image->link, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required',
        'placeholder' => '1']); !!}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
       {!! Form::label('image ID', 'Image Id:*') !!}
        {!! Form::text("images[$key][id]", $image->id, ['class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => '1']); !!}
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  </div>
@endforeach
```

In the controller where I proccess the request, i have to identify which id is missing from the $property_images so it will be deleted from the database. So I also retreive $property_images from a $property via a hasMany relationship as shown in the code below:

```
 $property = Property::findOrFail($id);
$output = ['success' => 0,
           'msg' => 'Something went wrong!'
];
                    
if($property){
    $property_attributes = $property->attributes;
    $property_images = $property->images;
    
    try {
        DB::beginTransaction();

        $property->fill($request->validated());
        $property_attributes->fill($request->only(['floor']));

        foreach ($property_images as $pImg) {
            $delete = true;
            foreach ($request->images as $image) {
                if ($image['id'] == $pImg->id) {
                    $delete = false;
                }
            }

            if ($delete) {
                $pImg->delete();
            }
        }
```

As I want to match the id from the images of the database array with the images of the request array, is there any way ro replace the two foreach functions with built-in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Laravel` collections to your advantage, it is a very powerful part of `Laravel`. Find all the images that are not in the request by using [whereNotIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-wherenotin) on the id and [plucking](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-pluck) it from the request. Then use [Higher Order Messages](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#higher-order-messages) call to delete em easily.

```
$property->images
    ->whereNotIn('id', collect($request->images)->pluck('id'))
    ->each->delete();
```

Comment: Wow reduced in one line. Nice. I will read more about collections.